# I can't access my computer through specific port?

Tags: networking, iptables, fedora

On Fedora I tried to access port 1521, so I opened the following port on my firewall:

```
$ sudo iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo service iptables save
```

I then tried to telnet to my inner IP (the IP that the router gave me) and got connection refused:

```
$ telnet 192.168.1.103 1521
Trying 192.168.1.103...

telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.103: Connection refused
```

I then tried to telnet to my internet IP and didn't get any response:

```
$ telnet x.x.x.x 1521
Trying x.x.x.x...
```

As far as I can tell, I've opened my port on the router also, BTW, I also tried it with port 22 and got the same result.

Comment: you may have better luck on Server Fault.

Comment: is there actually a listening socket on that port? `netstat -tnl | grep :1521`

Comment: yes there is, oracle listener

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this. I don't believe the `-m` switch can take the argument `tcp`.

Based on the state of the connection being "new":

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT
```

Accept any connections on port 1521:

```
$ iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT
```

Also is there a daemon listening on this port 1521?

Comment: didnt helped. there is an oracle listener, i'm trying telnet and also tnsping.

Comment: Can you `telnet localhost 1521` on the actual host running Oracle?

Comment: Yes I can, and also 192.168.1.103 is good. but not the internet ip

Comment: @nir - then your issue likely lies with the router. It doesn't appear to be forwarding traffic correctly to port 1521 on host 192.168.1.103. What you have here is all you need to do to accept the traffic on port 1521 on the linux box's firewall.

Comment: @nir - I would focus on getting `ssh` port forwarded first. Once that is forwarding without issue then ove to Oracle. Oracle can be trickier and in the past I've had problems with `tnsping`. You have to explicitly configure the listener and clients so that it works correctly.